# Multipe ModelAttributes of same type in post method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have this page where a teacher can invite a student to the platform. This works just fine, but now I would like to implement multiple invites on the same page. In short, there now is a form with the possibility to invite 1 student at a time, but I would like to expand this to 5 students in one post method.

This is the page to invite 1 student:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="wrapper">
    <form class="form-activate" th:action="@{/invite}" method="post" th:object="${user}">
        <h2 class="form-activate-heading" th:text="#{invite.title}">Nodig een student uit</h2>
        <p th:text="#{invite.email}">Vul hier het e-mailadres in van de student die je wil uitnodigen:</p>       
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-lg" data-validation="email"
                   placeholder="Email" tabindex="2" th:attr="placeholder=#{general.email}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Invite"  th:attr="value=#{invite.enter}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Now I tried modifying this page for 2 users:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="wrapper">
    <form class="form-activate" th:action="@{/invite}" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-activate-heading" th:text="#{invite.title}">Nodig een student uit</h2>
        <p th:text="#{invite.email}">Vul hier het e-mailadres in van de student die je wil uitnodigen:</p>
        <div class="form-group" th:object="${user}">
            <input type="text" name="email" th:field="*{email}" class="form-control input-lg" data-validation="email"
                   placeholder="Email" tabindex="2" th:attr="placeholder=#{general.email}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" th:object="${user}">
            <input type="text" name="email" th:field="*{email}" class="form-control input-lg" data-validation="email"
                   placeholder="Email" tabindex="2" th:attr="placeholder=#{general.email}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Invite"  th:attr="value=#{invite.enter}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Then in my post method I tried to do it like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/invite", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView SendInvite(ModelAndView modelAndView, @ModelAttribute User user1, @ModelAttribute User user2, BindingResult bindingResult, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, HttpServletRequest request){
    List<User> students = new ArrayList<>();
    students.add(user1);
    students.add(user2);
    for (User user : students) {
```

But the page is not even loading anymore, here is my get method:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/invite", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showInvitePage(ModelAndView modelAndView, @ModelAttribute User user){
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Which gives me the following error:

Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor' (teacher/invite:20)] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:144)

Is it even possible what I'm trying to do ?

EDIT: I'm trying to implement to solution Aleksandrs has given me, but Spring throws an error:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/invite", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showInvitePage(ModelAndView modelAndView){
    List<String> emailList = new ArrayList<>();
    modelAndView.addObject(emailList);
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/invite", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView SendInvite(ModelAndView modelAndView, List<String> emailList){
    System.out.println(emailList.get(0));
```

Eventhough I have instantiated the emailList in the Get method, I get the following error:

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.util.List]: Specified class is an interface] with root cause
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.util.List]: Specified class is an interface

**EDIT2:**

Finally got it working, thanks to Aleksandrs for the help! Solution:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/teacher/invite", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showInvitePage(ModelAndView modelAndView){
    logger.info("Entered showInvitePage function");
    List<String> email = new ArrayList<>();
    modelAndView.addObject("email", email);
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/invite", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView SendInvite(ModelAndView modelAndView, @AuthenticationPrincipal User currentUser, @RequestParam List<String> email){
    email.forEach(address -> {
// send the invites
});
```

And the invite page:

```
 <form class="form-activate" th:action="@{/invite}" method="post" >            
            <p th:text="#{invite.email}">Vul hier het e-mailadres in van de student die je wil uitnodigen:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-lg" data-validation="email"
                   placeholder="Email" tabindex="2" th:attr="placeholder=#{general.email}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email2" class="form-control input-lg" data-validation="email"
                   placeholder="Email" tabindex="2" th:attr="placeholder=#{general.email}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email3" class="form-control input-lg" data-validation="email"
                   placeholder="Email" tabindex="2" th:attr="placeholder=#{general.email}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Invite"  th:attr="value=#{invite.enter}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Pandian said the "user" binded twice but in this case you can use simple array to pass list of String into controller. Because the actual user must have many fields which isn't present in your template. So can recoment use something like this in template:

```
<form class="form-activate" th:action="@{/invite}" method="post">
    <h2 class="form-activate-heading" th:text="#{invite.title}">Nodig een student uit</h2>
    <p th:text="#{invite.email}">Vul hier het e-mailadres in van de student die je wil uitnodigen:</p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="email[]" class="form-control input-lg" data-validation="email"
               placeholder="Email" tabindex="2" th:attr="placeholder=#{general.email}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="email[]" class="form-control input-lg" data-validation="email"
               placeholder="Email" tabindex="2" th:attr="placeholder=#{general.email}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Invite"
                   th:attr="value=#{invite.enter}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/invite", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView SendInvite(List<String> emailAddressList) {
    // some stuff here
}
```

**EDIT:**

So, I'm not sure that my JavaScript code works but in your case HTML must be likethis:

```
<form class="form-activate" th:action="@{/invite}" method="post" id="myForm">
    <h2 class="form-activate-heading" th:text="#{invite.title}">Nodig een student uit</h2>
    <p th:text="#{invite.email}">Vul hier het e-mailadres in van de student die je wil uitnodigen:</p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="email[]" id="email" class="form-control input-lg" data-validation="email"
               placeholder="Email" tabindex="2" th:attr="placeholder=#{general.email}"/>
        <span style="cursor: pointer;"
              onclick="myForm.innerHTML = myForm.innerHTML + '' + this.parentNode.cloneNode(true);">+</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Invite"
                   th:attr="value=#{invite.enter}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And in controller I'll try to do like that:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/invite", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView SendInvite(ModelAndView modelAndView, @RequestParam List<String> email) {
    email.stream()
        .forEach(address -> {
            User u = userService.findByEmail(address);
            if (u == null) {
                // send email here for current user;
            }
        });
    // some other stuff
}
```

I can try to run it on my pc if you can tell me some test password.

Comment: Hi, how would the controller receive a List when the two input fields are an array? And wouldnt I have to declare the Array first beforehand? At the moment, the page just throws an error without any information.

Comment: Spring will make it instead of you. You only should only pass List as argument in your controller method. To prevent exception, you should make an ampty List and pass it into view. And in the template you'll check the list size, and if it it is empty, you can show blank fields.

Comment: hi @Aleksandrs,
I edited my original post with your solution but I'm still facing some difficulties, do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you share your project on github?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/KDG-Integratieproject/back-end.git
The question is regarding the invite.html page and the /invite method can be found in the RegisterController. The version from gitlab may vary.

Comment: Sorry, I gave you the url to clone it with git. This should be the working url where you can download it from: https://gitlab.com/KDG-Integratieproject/back-end

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out tonight !
I don't think you need a test password? The H2 data normally is accessible and any email address that is not in the data.sql file should be valid.

Comment: Test user is sauron - Pw: sauron

Comment: I fix the JavaScript error but in your java code something not good, because method annotated with `@RequestMapping("/invite")` not called.  Have you some filters or interceptors in your configuration? Excluding SpringSecurity?

Comment: Normally not, method is not configured in SpringSecurity because it is only accesible for teachers :/

Comment: The page is mapped to /teacher/invite btw. So it can be found at localhost:8080/teacher/invite

Comment: No, when you submit form, it send the data on localhost:8080/invite and that method not executed.

Comment: I tried changing the mapping of the method and the html page to /teacher/invite, but without success. I have noticed that in the AdministrationController, there is another method mapping the /teacher/invite url. But commenting it out did not work. Maybe my Get method is not correct?

Comment: the link on the teacher page was mapped to /teacher/invite but the get method was mapped to /invite, so the Get method from the Registercontroller was never called. In the Administrationcontroller, there was also a get method mapped to /teacher/invite so that one was called. I commented the AdministrationController method out and adjusted my get method in the RegisterController, but it's giving me a 400 bad request error.

Comment: I can make aditional review in the next 48 hours.

Comment: Hi, @Aleksandre Rudzitis, any luck on the review? I'm quite stuck

Answer (score 0):

Issues : same model "user" binded twice on same element with name "email"

Below Code working fine for me

```
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/accessSite}" method="post">
    <div th:object="${userVO}">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{name}" /></td>
                <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}">Name
                    Error</td>
            </tr>


        </table>
    </div>

    <div th:object="${employeeVO}">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{empname}" /></td>
                <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('empname')}" th:errors="*{empname}">Name
                    Error</td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
```

Submit

```
  @RequestMapping("/accessSite")
public String accessSite( UserVO userVO, EmployeeVO employeeVO,BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "form";
    }
    return "result";
}
```

Comment: Hi @Pandian,
That point is that I have to bind multiple User models and their email fields, so this wouldnt work for me.